# Why doesn't this html 'aside' appear on the side?

Tags: html

I'm using some very simple html that I would expect to produce a sidebar, but the text in the sidebar simply appears as a next paragraph on the same page.  True in both Chrome and Safari.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
     <section>
         <p>
         This is the main content.  I'm not content to have main content without a sidebar.
         </p>

     <aside>
         <p>
         As an aside, I want this to be at the side.
         </p>
     </aside>
     </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Do I need to add styling elements?  Based on the documents I wouldn't have thought so.  I have also tried this with a much longer 'section' text, to no avail.  I've also tried the `<sidebar>` tag.

Comment: I've just read the aside tag documentation on w3 schools: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_aside.asp. When I try the example it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Browsers have a default style sheet but it's never as aggressive as to affect the site layout. Presentation-oriented HTML tags are something from the early days of the WWW (I'm talking about the 1990s) and were superseded by CSS.

Comment: Hmm, as a software engineer who occasionally "drops in" to the html and css world, separated by years, it's an ongoing annoyance to have things be different every time, but that's really an aside.  The paragraph tag certainly changes site layout, as do the list tags.  Like with so many aspects of technology "it's all easy once you know how'.  Grr.  Thanks for weighing in though.

Comment: I've used the term "layout" referring exclusively to the overall distribution and positioning of page elements within the document. There's surely a more precise word for that (I'm not native speaker).

Comment: Browsers are allowed to format figures and asides specially, but as far as I know, none of them do.  You'll need something like this:  ``aside, figure { width: 33%; min-width: 10em; float: right; margin-left: .5em; border-style: solid; }`` in your style definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [HTML 5 specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-aside-element):

> The aside element represents a section of a page that consists of content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside element, and which could be considered separate from that content. Such sections are often represented as sidebars in printed typography.

It is not something that effect visually like other HTML tags.

Consider to use `Flexbox`

```css
#section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <section id="section">
    <p>
      This is the main content. I'm not content to have main content without a sidebar.
    </p>

    <aside id="aside">
      <p>
        As an aside, I want this to be at the side.
      </p>
    </aside>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also try to use [`float`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp).

Answer (score 1):

These html5 tags,

```html
<section>, <main>, <nav>
```

and so on, have no impact on the browser, it's like writing

```
<div>
```

.
The sole purpose of their existence is to make your source code more readable.
By the way, I do not think that  actually exists.

Comment: "*have no impact on the browser*" isn't quite true.  Browsers can have a mode that says to display only the essential parts, which would suppress things like ``<nav>`` and ``<aside>``.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use CSS for this. The semantic HTML tags - section, article, aside, etc... do not have a lot of impact on the rendering of the page. Some of them usually just add a default `display: block` style, but that's about it.